# Why does my code not process correctly it keeps returning the wrong line?

Tags: python, random

It is supposed to return a certain line if the Computer randomly picks a certain letter, but it chooses only one instance to repeat over and over again, even when the condition for the other sentence to be printed is met.

```
import random
Player_Score = 0
Computer_Score = 0
while Player_Score < 5 or Computer_Score < 5:
    Player_object = input("Would you like to choose R, P, or S?")
    Computer_object = str(random.sample(set(["R", "P", "S"]), 1))
    if Player_object == "R" or Player_object == "r":
        if str(Computer_object) == "R":
             print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ".You have tied with the Computer and neither of you have scored a point.")
        elif str(Computer_object) == "P":
            Computer_Score = Computer_Score + 1
            print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ". You have been beaten by the Computer and it has scored a point.")
        else:
            Player_Score = Player_Score + 1
            print("You have chosen " +Player_object+ " and the Computer chose " +str(Computer_object)+ ".You have beaten the Computer scored a point.")
```

This code returns these results:

```
    Would you like to choose R, P, or S?R
You have chosen R and the Computer chose ['R'].You have beaten the Computer scored a point.
Would you like to choose R, P, or S?R
You have chosen R and the Computer chose ['P'].You have beaten the Computer scored a point.
Would you like to choose R, P, or S?R
You have chosen R and the Computer chose ['S'].You have beaten the Computer scored a point.
Would you like to choose R, P, or S?R
You have chosen R and the Computer chose ['S'].You have beaten the Computer scored a point.
Would you like to choose R, P, or S?R
You have chosen R and the Computer chose ['R'].You have beaten the Computer scored a point.
Would you like to choose R, P, or S?R
You have chosen R and the Computer chose ['P'].You have beaten the Computer scored a point.
Would you like to choose R, P, or S?
```

Comment: `random.sample` returns a list, so `str(Computer_object)` will never equal `"R"`, `"P"`, etc..  Try printing the value of `random.sample(set(["R", "P", "S"]), 1)` to see what I mean, and then use `random.sample(set(["R", "P", "S"]), 1)[0]` and note the difference.

Comment: When you asked almost the same question yesterday (https://stackoverflow.com/q/47288060/4996248) someone pointed out to you that your use of `random.sample()` was wrong and they recommended `random.choice()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

`str(random.sample(set(["R", "P", "S"]), 1))` returns `"['S']"`, not `'S'`, so your code always enters the else condition.

Instead, try `random.sample("RPS", 1)[0]`, which will return the first (and only) element of the list or use `random.choice('RPS')`.

Comment: Or skip the indexing and use `random.choice(seq)`.